# Date type field binding issue in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Here is my projectController:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("myApp");

    var projectController = function ($scope, $location) {

        var currentDate = new Date();
        $scope.startDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate());
    };

    app.controller("projectController", projectController);
}());
```

This is my control binding:

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control"  name="startDate" ng-model='startDate' />
                            <span class="text-danger" ng-show="myForm.startDate.$error.date">Not a valid date.</span>
```

But when value shows in the control **"2016-02-15"**.  How can I show the date in **MM/dd/yyyy** format in the control?

Comment: What browser are you using? Support for the *date* input types is very bad

Comment: I am using IE 11 for testing.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Browser_compatibility. You're better off using a text input and adding a formatting directive.

Comment: If I make input type="text" than will ng-model field with date filter work?

Comment: no. The expression passed to `ng-model` must be assignable.

Answer (score 1):

You can display the date in your expected output by getting the day, month and year and stored each in variable.

This is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rrwfu834/1/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="DateCtrl">
    <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="startDate" ng-model='startDate' />
      <span class="text-danger" ng-show="myForm.startDate.$error.date">Not a valid date.
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
angular.module('test', []);
  angular.module('test').controller('DateCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; // + 1 Because the month starts to 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if (dd < 10) {
       dd = '0' + dd
    }

    if (mm < 10) {
      mm = '0' + mm
    }

    $scope.startDate = today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
 });
```

Comment: This will trigger a type / format error. The model for `datetime-local` must be  a `Date` instance

Answer (score 0):

you can use angular-datepicker.
Code will look like:

```
<input date-time format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm">
```

[datepicker](https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker)

You can also validate with ng-pattern to match regex.

Answer (score -1):

You can add date filter to parse your date :

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control"  name="startDate" ng-model='startDate' />
                        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="myForm.startDate.$error.date | date: 'mediumDate' ">Not a valid date.</span>
```

AND if you want to set your date from controller in mm/dd/yy format then use :

```
$scope.result = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'mediumDate');
```